# How to query chatter questions in apex?

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-answers

I want to query chatter question in a soql query. Can anybody specifies the query. Thanks

Comment: If your chatter answer is enabled in your org.. you can easily access using soql `SELECT Body, Id FROM Question`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Question](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_question.htm) object to get the chatter questions in apex. Or if you want to use Rest API then you can also access them in REST API

1. To use Chatter REST API to work with Chatter Questions, use these resources.
   To post a question, make a POST request to the /chatter/feeds/news/userId/feed-items resource using the Attachment Input: Question request body.
2. To get the best answer of a question feed item, make a GET request to the new /chatter/feed-items/feedItemId/question resource.
   To update the best answer for a question, make a PATCH request to /chatter/feed-items/feedItemId/question and pass the bestAnswerId parameter or a Feed Question Input request body.
3. To search for question and answers suggestions, make a GET request to the new /connect/question-and-answers/suggestions resource.

[Reference](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_chatter_api_resources.htm#ChatterQuestionsTitle)

Answer (score 1):

Note, it appears that `Question` is no longer a supported sObject...

It is replaced by `FeedItem` of Type "QuestionPost"

Related Question/Answer:
[The Question Object is unavailable/not supported in My Org, even with chatter question enabled?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/322047/the-question-object-is-unavailable-not-supported-in-my-org-even-with-chatter-qu)