# The Question Object is unavailable/not supported in My Org, even with chatter question enabled?

Tags: lightning-community, chatter-feed

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_question.htm

This developer doc describes the details about the Question object, and I have added the Question action to the global publisher layout. But I couldn't understand why the Question object would be unavailable in my salesforce sandbox org.

Have tried using the query below
< SELECT Id, BestReplyId FROM Question >
in the developer console and workbench (API 49 )

returns error:

'ERROR at Row:1:Column:22
sObject type 'Question' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'

Trying to get the "BestReplySelectedById" ...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the question object is not functional. The developer console does not allow a query on this object (even using tooling API). The below snippet from the anonymous block gives "Invalid type: question"

```
List<question> SobjLst = [select BestReplyId from question];
system.debug(SobjLst);
```

GET request made using `/services/data/v49.0/sobjects` also does not show the Question object. There aren't any settings that we can use to disable/enable access to the questions object.(See related [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IQaY))

The data of "Ask a Question" appearing on the community is stored on the Feed Item object. Running SOQL on [Feed Item object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) with networkID as community Id and type as "Question Post" should fetch you the desired result.

```
select Id, Body,BestCommentId, CommentCount,Networkscope, CreatedDate, LikeCount, LinkUrl, ParentId, RelatedRecordId, Title, Type from FeedItem where Type='QuestionPost' and Networkscope='0DB7F000000CbHSWA0'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did found the question data stored in the FeedItem Object, but the fields on the FeedItem object seems very different from the Question Object, thus, I couldn't get fields value like "BestReplySelectedById". Not sure why Salesforce changed this.

Comment: You need to query 2 objects to get to the commenter ID: the FeedItem, to get those posts with the best comment selected, and then FeedComment, to get the commenter ID.


select createdbyid ,CommentBody,InsertedById from feedcomment where feeditemId in( select Id from FeedItem where Type='QuestionPost' and Networkscope='0DB7F000000CbHSWA0' and BestCommentId='0D77F000002l5iKSAQ')

Comment: Thank you Swetha for the response! Your solution could get the user's ID whom posted the best comment, but do you know how to get the ID who selected the comment to be the best answer?